# animating jQuery Ui position()

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, jquery-animate, positioning

How can I animate from current position to center using `position({of:,my:,at:})`?
Is there any way to automate the process, or do I have to animate the CSS properties manually?

Comment: See the function http://api.jquery.com/animate/, you can specify a set of CSS values and jQUery will do the transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)?

Edit: Now that I understand what you are looking for a bit better, [here is a jQuery plugin that I wrote to do this very thing](https://github.com/DoomHamster/Align-jQuery-Plugin).

[Here's a quick jsFiddle as an example](http://jsfiddle.net/DoomHamster/Vabcs/).

I made the options a configurable object. Example:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $('#blah').align({speed:1000,y:false});
});​
```

EDIT: taking out the other code since it is no longer necessary and just cluttered things up.  Cleaning up my new code.  Fixed the offset parent positioning issues.  Added a link to the git repository and jsFiddle using the latest version of the source.

Comment: I know about that, but then I'll have to calculate the div's      width-height divide by 2, etc.. I was wondering if there was a way to animate, say:  position({of:,my:,at:, animate: slide}), or something of the sort.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/MjsDc/8/ This would solve it, but it's kinda messy. I wanted a solution to go with position({of:,my:,at:}).

Comment: @localhost2 OK...I've written code for this actually....it was an object centering jQuery extension that I used on a client site...have to see if I can dig it up...

Comment: That nearly does it. Had to change offset to position(), and there are some extra pixels top and left. Trying to fix that.

Comment: @localhost2 yeah....I am noticing some inaccurate behavior as well....need to fully revisit the code and make it better now that I am more experienced with such things.

Comment: @localhost2 looks like the positioning problems are related to the behavior of position:absolute.  If you take position:relative off the parent, it works fine.  Will need to add code to detect the type of positioning before making the calculations.

Comment: OK...final version fixed the positioning issues.

Answer (score 28):

This answer may have been right back in February, but now there is a much easier way.

The position method takes a `using` argument just for this purpose.  For example:

```
$(div).position({
    at: "left+50% top+50%",
    of: $(div).parent(),
    using: function(css, calc) {
        $(this).animate(css, 200, "linear");
    }
});
```